# Add a GPG key for an Artifactory debian repo

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I need to add a custom debian package from artifactory to my server.

The issue is that I manage to upload the package and sign it but when it comes to do `sudo apt-get update` I get

```
W: GPG error: https://mycompany.jfrog.io/mycompany/deb-release-local bionic Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 782E27A43CDD3263
```

Now, the gpg keys (pub and priv) have been added to artifactory although I have not found a way to add it to my local apt. I have tried:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 782E27A43CDD3263
```

but without luck. I have tried to change the keyserver to point to my artifactory endpoint but it times out.

Answer (score 0):

Since the keypair it was created by me, I simply had to add my key by running:

```
cat mykey | apt-key add -
```

and then run `apt-get update`